# Add comments in hive table from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, hive, comments, metadata

Helloo everyone!

I try to add comments to tables metadata in hive.
I have a csv file containing all the comment I need to add, but I do not know the most efficient way to do it.
Should I use Python to add comments from a csv file to a hive table comment or import my csv file into a hive table and feed the comments?

In those two ways, i did not manage to do it...
When I try to load the csv file into a table (load data local inpath - or - create table location), it does not work :/

Do you know how to do it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: you can definitely pull the data from the CSV using python, but could you by chance give a bit of context as to what hive is? I think I can give some assistance!

Comment: Hive is an apache tool where you can code sql queries :) i have tables where the comment part (in the metadata when you use describe) is empty. The comments are in a csv file and i soule like to import my csv file into a table but i do not well the query to do it